# Python:Project Euler #1

Tags: python

I've tried looking up some questions that were already on StackOverflow for project Euler problem 1 but not much has helped me. This is my code, it runs, but it's not correct. not sure whats wrong?

```
def sumOfMultiples(number):

    sum = 0

    for i in range(1,number):

        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:

            sum += 1

    return sum

print (sumOfMultiples(15))
```

Comment: You need to explain *how* it is not correct and what the expected output should be.  Those unfamiliar with Project Euler will be confused.

Comment: Why are you adding `1` instead of `i`?  Your function isn't called `countOfMultiples`.  Also `range(1, n)` ends at `n - 1`.

Comment: I haven't seen anyone mention that you are only looking for numbers from 1 to 15 instead of 1 to 1000.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using `i` at all. When the number meets the condition (divisible by 3 or 5), you want to add it, not 1.

```
        sum += 1
```

should be

```
        sum += i
```

Answer (score 3):

The [question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) asks for "the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000". You're adding 1 to the sum instead of adding the multiple of 3 or 5 to the sum.

So `sum += 1` should be `sum += i`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import time
#Recording start time of the program
start=time.time()
#A variable to store the sum 
result=0

#calculating the sum for all the numbers below 1000
for i in range(1,1000):
#Checking the the condition 
    if i%3==0 or i%5==0:
     result=result+i
print("Sum of all numbers that are multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 is",result)
print("Execution time of program is",time.time()-start)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumOfMultiples(number):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1,number):
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
            sum += i
    return sum

print (sumOfMultiples(15))
```

In place of sum+=1 write sum+=i.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you post an answer, consider what new thing it brings to the table based on the rest of the answers. At the moment, you're only iterating what has already been said.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single-liner for you to ponder:

```
print sum([x for x in xrange(1,1000) if x%3==0 or x%5==0])
```

or you could also do it like this:

```
print sum([[0,x][x%3==0 or x%5==0] for x in xrange(1,10**3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
def sumOfMultiples(number):

    sum = 0

    for i in range(1,number):

        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:

            sum += i       ## You needed to add i, not 1. Probably just a type-o as they are similar looking characters.

    print(sum)

(sumOfMultiples(1000))      ## Also Euler1 requires this input to be 1000 for correct answer.
```